# Number of mysql slave impact mysql master performance

Tags: mysql

Is there any relation between number of mysql slave and performance of master mysql.

Currently I have 3 slave replicating from master. Will it impact read/write performance of master database if I add new slave to master ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be fine. Increasing the replica count from 3 to 4 should not have a noticeable affect on the master.

In very large OLTP systems it is possible to saturate the network interface on the master DB by having too many replicas. In the past booking.com has mentioned having that issue with 50-100 replicas. You can read more about their problem and solution [here](https://blog.booking.com/mysql_slave_scaling_and_more.html).